# What is the time complexity of this algorithm that has binary search along with while loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to figure out the running time complexity of the **findingDup** algorithm because I'm unsure if it's O(n) or O(log n). My goal is to implement a sublinear algorithm that finds how many times an **int value** is duplicated. You can assume the given array **int[] A** is always sorted. If you have any additional questions please leave them below.

```
public class Controller {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        int[] A = {-1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 10};
        
        int value = 6;
        
        System.out.println(findingDup(A, value));
        
    }// end main
    
    public static int findingDup(int[] a, int x){
        
        int counter = 0;
        
        int index = binarySearch(a, x); // index = 4 
        
        int leftIndex = index - 1;      // leftIndex = 3
        int rightIndex = index + 1;     // rightIndex = 5
        
        if(index == -1){
            return 0;
        }
        else if(a[index] == x){
            counter++;
        }
        
        // checking if all numbers are dups
        if(a[0] == a[a.length - 1]){
            return a.length;
        }
        
        if(leftIndex >= 0){
            
            while(a[leftIndex] == x){
                counter++;
                leftIndex--;
                
                if(leftIndex < 0){
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        if(rightIndex <= a.length - 1){
           
            while(a[rightIndex] == x){
                counter++;
                rightIndex++;
                
                if(rightIndex > a.length - 1){
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        return counter;
        
    }// end method
    
    public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int x){
    
    int low = 0, high = a.length - 1;
    
    while(low <= high){
        
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        
        if(a[mid] < x){
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else if(a[mid] > x){
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else{
            return mid;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
    
    }// End Method
    
    
}// end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is O(k + log n), where "k" is number of times the value is present on the list.

If the k = O(n) it degrades to O(n).

As an example, in the extreme case of the list being [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, ...] you will end-up processing all the elements.

You can still fix this problem by running more than one binary search.

First you run it to find first occurrence of "value", and then you run it again to find a first number larger than value (search for value+1).

Your binary search algorithm needs to be modified to return the first occurrence of the value, or larger value if the value cannot be found.

As of now it finds any occurrence, not guaranteed to be the first one nor the last one.

Your binary search has the following condition:

```
if (smaller) {...}
else if (larger) {...}
else {we have found it!}
```

So it can return any occurrence.

You should be looking for an index that:

```
a[mid - 1] < value && a[mid] >= value
```

mid-1 can be smaller than 0, so you need to check for that first.

If this is not the case, we haven't found the first occurrence, and need to move either left or right index.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you can run the binary search again to find a different occurrence? I'm still confused about how you would approach that.

Comment: Expanded answer.